# Converting htaccess to Nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

Hello stackoverflow Users,

i found a nice Tutorial about PHP routing on the Internet. My Problem is that i am using Nginx on my Server. I test some Solutions that i found on the Internet, but nothing works :(
For frameworks like Laravel i am using:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

This is .htaccess from the Tutorial:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /MYBASEPATH

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1;
}
```